# Access non static function from static function

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Here is some insight: I am working with UnityScript in Unity 4.6.3. I have one script called Pause.js and it contains this function:

```
function fadeMusicOut () {
    while (audio.volume >= 0.005) {
    yield WaitForSeconds(0.1);
    Debug.Log("Loop Entered: " + audio.volume);
    audio.volume = (audio.volume - 0.015);
}
```

Another script GameManager.js has this function:

```
static function Score (wallName : String) {
    if (wallName == "rightWall") {
        playerScore01 += 1;
    }
    else {
        playerScore02 += 1;
    }
    if (playerScore01 == SettingsBack.scoreLimit || playerScore02 == SettingsBack.scoreLimit)
    {
        startParticles = 1;
        SettingsBack.gameOver = 1;
        BallControl.fadeSound = 1;
        yield WaitForSeconds(4);
        Camera.main.SendMessage("fadeOut");
        Pause.fadeMusic = 1;
        SettingsBack.soundVolume = 0;
        yield WaitForSeconds(2);
        playerScore01 = 0;
        playerScore02 = 0;
        SettingsBack.soundVolume = oldSoundVol;
        Application.LoadLevel("_Menu");
    }
}
```

So pretty much I want to call the `fadeMusicOut()` function from `static function Score`, but it will not let me because it says it needs an instance of that object.

The Pause.js script is not attached to any game objects, but it is attached to 2 buttons that call their specific functions. The GameManager.js script is attached to an object called GM. So how can I go about calling `fadeMusicOut()` from the Score function?

I have tried setting new vars that import the game object but still no luck. I tried making `fadeMusicOut()` a static function, but it creates many errors.

Any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: There is no way. Make the fade out function static and fix the other errors.